# Package CSS with AngularJS Module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a stand alone module that I would like to use in multiple projects or maybe make a bower package out of. I figured out how to package the html templates by converting them to js but I can't figure out a good way to package some CSS with it.

I tried out [angular-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-css) and it does what I need with one downfall, it requires me to specify the file path to the CSS relative to the index.html. This is a problem as the file structures may be different in different projects and I would like this to be packaged in a way that it can just be added to the project and work.

As it stands I'm adding CSS with the method below but I'm not sure this is really a good way to do it. I can add the CSS this way and only add it once but I cant remove it when it's not needed

In the directives controller I use this code to add CSS styles

```
var markerAnim = document.getElementById('markerAnim');

if (!markerAnim) {
    var markerStyles = {
        animation: 'some css',
        locMarker: 'more css',
        after: 'a little more css'
    };

    var styleSheet = markerStyles.animation + markerStyles.locMarker + markerStyles.after;
    angular.element(document).find('head').prepend('<style id="markerAnim" type="text/css">' + styleSheet + '</style>');
}
```

Comment: Consider using [Webpack and style-loader](https://github.com/dmachat/angular-webpack-cookbook/wiki/Loading-CSS).

Comment: @estus Thank you so much for this suggestion. Webpack was exactly what I needed and it took less code and  time to setup than Grunt.

Comment: You're welcome. Webpack has steep learning curve but is worth it. Also, it plays nice together with Gulp if extra flexibility is needed